# How should I localise time spans using ICU?

Tags: c++, time, icu

I am generating strings like:

> 3 days, 5 hours, 24 minutes
>   9 days, 1 minute
>   2 hours, 8 minutes
>   59 minutes
>   32 seconds

What is the conventional way to localise these using ICU?

I see plenty of features for localising dates and times, but not time spans.

I don't want to just localise the words individually, as that may not be sufficiently robust for some languages.

Comment: What you mean localising time spans? As i know ICU is related with character encoding. i dont know if it has any relation with date time terms.

Comment: @idris: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime http://userguide.icu-project.org/i18n

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of how you use ICU time spans to produce one of those strings, like "32 seconds"?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not really, no: this question is asking "how to do that".

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood "_I am generating strings like: ..._".

Have you looked at [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) and the localized conversion
specifiers in [`std::strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)? I'm not sure it'll take you all the way to the format you want, but probably close. In C++20 it should get easier if that's any comfort :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am generating those strings by simply concatenating words and numbers. I'd like instead to have ICU produce them for me but I can't seem to find this functionality.  Perhaps it's not there. Unfortunately `strftime` also does not include this, only localised absolute dates/times.

Comment: I see. I downloaded and compiled ICU but it's a real mess i.m.o. It has close to 500 header files and the documentation doesn't say what you should include so I tried including all of them, but that caused name collisions and other problems. It uses reserved identifiers and has a lot of problems it seems. I had to turn off all warnings. Too much work for me I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for looking @Ted. FWIW ICU is fairly industry-standard so I'm surprised you've had so much trouble with it, but I'm fortunate to have "inherited" its use in a project rather than having to set it up from scratch, so I don't have experience doing so :)

Comment: I managed to get a maintainable list of header files after having installed it properly (only 187 header files) - but I don't find much useful information in the online documentation, but I could have been looking in the wrong place (http://userguide.icu-project.org/).